# System.Net.HttpClient.PostAsync work in UWP, but not working in .Net Standard Library

Tags: win-universal-app, dotnet-httpclient, standard-library

a have UWP app, that working correctly. Now i working on .Net Standard Library providing same function and i do not now, what I'm doing wrong.

UWP code (working correctly)

```
private async void btnRVM_ClickR(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                Uri uri = new Uri("http://examplecom/api/Account/Register");
                HttpContent content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new RegistrationObject(tbxUsername.Text, tbxPassword.Text, tbxConfirm.Text)), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");                
                try
                {
                    HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(uri, content);


                }
                catch (Exception e1)
                {
                    string excMessage = e1.ToString();
                }

            }
```

But  almost same code in .Net standard library do not working

```
public static async Task<object> RegisterAsync(string username, string password, string confirmPassword)
        {
            using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                Uri uri = new Uri("http://example/api/Account/Register");
                HttpContent content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new RegistrationObject(username, password, confirmPassword)), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                try
                {
                    HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(uri, content);


                }
                catch (Exception e1)
                {
                    string excMessage = e1.ToString();
                }



                return Task.FromResult<object>(null);


            }
        }
```

Comment: what's happening? deadlock? try `PostAsync(uri, content).ConfigureAwait(false);`

Comment: Now it seems like IIS requires different permissions and my code will working correctly.